# How get limited number of input in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am a newbie in Haskell.
Let says my program want to calculate something from this pattern of input:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
...
16 b6 c6
```

The input contains 6 lines and each line has 3 numbers
I want to get data as [(Integer, Integer, Integer)] but limit the length of the list to be only 6 before going to the calculation.

How could I do this? Also, how could I get a length from [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'd start with `readFile`, `splitOn`, and `read`, and then post what you have as a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three steps to this:

1. Read 6 lines
2. Break each line into the (hopefully three) parts
3. Convert to the desired result

Some sample code is below:

```
input = do
  lines <- sequence $ take 6 $ repeat readLn
  let table = words <$> lines
  return [(a, b, c) | [a,b,c] <- table]
```

This gives `input :: IO [(String, String, String)]` but I'm sure you could modify this to give you what you want.

Comment: Or with lazy IO if you'd like: `map words . take 6  . lines <$> getContents :: IO [[String]]`.  Or with `Control.Monad` imported: `map words <$> replicateM 6 readLn`.